# How to add login attempt in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to add login attempt on mysql using php codes?
:ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN login_attempts INT DEFAULT 0;

ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN login_attempts INT DEFAULT 0;
but how on php codes?
i have a column users on my table

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking specifically. See [ask]. If you want help with something in your php code, please show relevant parts of the php code and explain the exact problem you're having

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ensure that your users table has a column named login_attempts. You can add this column using a SQL query like:
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN login_attempts INT DEFAULT 0;
then.>

In your PHP login script, you need to check the login attempts before allowing a user to log in. If the number of login attempts exceeds a certain limit, you may want to lock the account or implement some delay to prevent brute force attacks.

Here's a simplified example your php code, let we call "create_blocked.php":

```
<?php
$sql_update_attempts = "UPDATE users SET login_attempts = login_attempts + 1 WHERE username = ?";
    $stmt_update_attempts = $conn->prepare($sql_update_attempts);
    $stmt_update_attempts->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt_update_attempts->execute();
$max_attempts = 3;
    if ($stmt_update_attempts->affected_rows >= $max_attempts) {
        // Lock the account or implement other security measures
        echo "Account locked due to multiple failed login attempts.";
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is the reson that "affected_rows" (in an update query) be used to do the comparison ?

Comment: In PHP, after executing an SQL UPDATE query using MySQLi, the affected_rows property is used to determine the number of rows affected by the most recent INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE, or DELETE query. It provides information about the number of rows that were changed by the last operation.

In the context of the login attempt example, the affected_rows is used to check how many rows were affected by the UPDATE query to increment the login attempts count. Here's why it is used in this scenario:

Comment: @DeviceSaviorDevS `$stmt_update_attempts->affected_rows` will most likely be `1` when the row (the one with the correct username) is changed. This means that value will never be greater or equal `3`, making the `if()` statement useless (it will always be `false`)

Comment: @DeviceSaviorDevS it's true that affected_rows does that. But ask yourself: how does that help you to determine the number of login attempts that user has made? All it will tell you is that it updated 1 row. To find the new total number of login attempts you'll need to make a SELECT query. Also, your code doesn't deal with resetting the number of attempts to 0 following a successful login